# How to make a spec file when using gets

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code which using gets. Now I want to make a spec file. Usually I make a spec file for class or def, but I am not sure how to do it in this case. Can I make a spec file for a file using gets?

I appreciate any inputs.

```
while n = gets.to_i
  break if n.zero?
  dataset = {}
  dataset.default = 0
  n.times do 
    id, price, quantity = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
    dataset[id] += price * quantity
  end
  more_than_mil =  dataset.select { |key, val| val >= 1_000_000 }.keys
  puts more_than_mil.empty? ? "NA" : more_than_mil
end
```

Inputs for above code.

```
1001 2000 520
1002 1800 450
1003 1600 625
1001 200 1220
2
1001 100 3
1005 1000 100
2
2013 5000 100
2013 5000 100
0
```

Outputs

```
1001
1003
NA
2013
```

Answer (score 0):

The [aruba-rspec](https://github.com/livinginthepast/aruba-rspec) allows you to spec arbitrary command line tools, including standalone ruby files you may have written.

You could also refactor this code so that it is not just one chunk of code. For example, separate the part that reads the input from the part that performs the calculations and test those component parts as you would normally